# not_analyzed for search and analyzed for visual in kibana

Tags: charts, line, kibana

I have a problem with analyzed or not string fields. Because i need "analyzed" data for searchs, and "not_analyzed" when i do a top N report, for example with "vertical line chart"

It's posible use any filter or exclude/include Pattern to keep the full string without analyzed in visuals ??

Im using Version 4.1.1 of Kibana.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch has different analyzers called index analyzer and search analyzer. You can use different analyzers for both.
This link here might give you a solution: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_controlling_analysis.html